# How can I remove zeroes from a linspace list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linspace

My list is this:

```
np.linspace(-20,20)
```

I want to get everything except for the zeroes.

I tried this:

```
x = list(map(int, np.linspace(-20,20)))
x.remove(0)
```

Also this:

```
[int(x) for x in np.linspace(-20,20) if x!=0]
```

But none of it worked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "none of it worked"? What did you get instead of what you wanted to get?

Comment: Keep in mind that `remove` removes the first, only one, matching entry (per call).  With the `int` conversion from floats, linspace can produce multiple 0's (and other integers).  Look at values at various stages of these conversions to have a clearer idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
arr = np.linspace(-20, 20, dtype=int)
print(arr[arr != 0])
```

Prints:

```
[-20 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -12 -11 -10  -9  -8  -7  -7
  -6  -5  -4  -3  -3  -2  -1   1   2   2   3   4   5   6   6   7   8   9
  10  11  11  12  13  14  15  15  16  17  18  19  20]
```

---

Or in plain Python:

```py
arr = [i for i in range(-20, 21) if i != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a numpy array without the zeroes, you can do:

```py
L = numpy.linspace(-20, 20)
L = L[L != 0]
```

`L != 0` creates an array of boolean that serves as a mask and `L[L != 0]` keeps the values where the mask is `True`.

However the output of `numpy.linspace(-20, 20)` does not have 0 in it.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have a zero when I print it, but I need it to make a graph, and linspace goes through the value of zero. It's my fault that I didn't specify what I use the values for.

Answer (score 1):

`np.linspace(-20,20)` wont have zeroes in it.

```
print(np.linspace(-20,20))

array([-20.        , -19.18367347, -18.36734694, -17.55102041,
       -16.73469388, -15.91836735, -15.10204082, -14.28571429,
       -13.46938776, -12.65306122, -11.83673469, -11.02040816,
       -10.20408163,  -9.3877551 ,  -8.57142857,  -7.75510204,
        -6.93877551,  -6.12244898,  -5.30612245,  -4.48979592,
        -3.67346939,  -2.85714286,  -2.04081633,  -1.2244898 ,
        -0.40816327,   0.40816327,   1.2244898 ,   2.04081633,
         2.85714286,   3.67346939,   4.48979592,   5.30612245,
         6.12244898,   6.93877551,   7.75510204,   8.57142857,
         9.3877551 ,  10.20408163,  11.02040816,  11.83673469,
        12.65306122,  13.46938776,  14.28571429,  15.10204082,
        15.91836735,  16.73469388,  17.55102041,  18.36734694,
        19.18367347,  20.        ])
```

If you want values from -20 to 20 without 0 you can simply do with a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in range(-20,20) if x!=0]
```

---

`np.linspace(-20,20)` Returns evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval. These will be 50 values.

> Number of samples to generate. Default is 50. Must be non-negative.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: His conversion to an int list can produce multiple 0s.  `remove` only removes one match at a time.  I think that's what's confusing him.

Comment: Yeah that confused me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to illustrate my comment, to give a clearer idea of what's happening with your `remove`

Make a smaller linspace, with only 10 elements (still even number, just not the default 50):

```
In [105]: x=np.linspace(-5,5,10);x
Out[105]: 
array([-5.        , -3.88888889, -2.77777778, -1.66666667, -0.55555556,
        0.55555556,  1.66666667,  2.77777778,  3.88888889,  5.        ])
```

Since it includes the end points an even number of elements can give fractional spacings.

Convert that to int (same as your list/map/int)

```
In [106]: x.astype(int)
Out[106]: array([-5, -3, -2, -1,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  5])
```

Note the 0s.

```
In [107]: y=x.astype(int).tolist()    
In [108]: y.remove(0)    
In [109]: y
Out[109]: [-5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]    
In [110]: y.remove(0)    
In [111]: y
Out[111]: [-5, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

We have to call `remove` twice to get rid of both.

Repeat, but with an odd number:

```
In [112]: x=np.linspace(-5,5,11);x
Out[112]: array([-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])

In [113]: x.astype(int)
Out[113]: array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5])

In [114]: y=x.astype(int).tolist()    
In [115]: y.remove(0)

In [116]: y
Out[116]: [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now there's only one 0, and remove takes care off it.

Whether these numbers are what you really need or not, this explains why `remove` didn't remove (all) the zeros.